# regex to catch variables in a video wordpress shortcode

Tags: regex, wordpress, video, shortcode

I'm using regex to catch variables within a `[video]` shortcode in wordpress.

Imagine different shortcodes. One could look like this:

```
[video width="1080" height="1920" mp4="http://path-to-video/20160119_144218.mp4" autoplay="true" webm="http://path-to-video/20160119_144218_1.webm"][/video]
```

another one, like this:

```
[video width="720" height="1280" mp4="http://path-to-video/VID_20160118_134920.mp4" autoplay="true" poster="http://path-to-image/2016-01-23-16_23_45-Export-Settings-1.jpg"][/video]
```

the purpose of my regex is to retrieve the `mp4` and `webm` variables.

THE CATCH is that, sometimes, only the `mp4` source is present; sometimes both are present.
Other info, like `autoplay` or `poster` *might or might not* be there, in the order wordpress likes.

So I need a **conditional regex** that takes this into account and doesn't fail if no webm is present.

Originally I had this one:

```
\[video .* mp4="(.*?)".*webm="(.*?)"\]\[/video\]
```

Which worked perfectly with a shortcode with both `mp4` and `webm` (trusting wordpress would, as it seems to be doing for some reason, always put the webm at the end), but would fail when the `webm` was not present.

Now I'm trying with conditional regex but with no great success.

Here's what I have:

```
\[video .* mp4="(.*?)".*(?(?=.*webm=)webm="(.*?)"\]\[/video\]|.*\]\[/video\])
```

The above catches the `mp4` value just fine in both the examples given above: but where the webm is present, it will ignore it.

I'm worried that, even if I manage to retrieve both variables, other variations of the info in the shortcode could throw my regex off.

Can you help me create a better, fool-proof, regex???

Comment: Try [`\[video\b[^]]*\smp4="([^"]*)"(?:(?!\swebm=)[^]])*(?:\swebm="([^"]*)")?[^]]*]\[\/video]`](https://regex101.com/r/pG8aR8/1).

Comment: Why would you try and parse a shortcode yourself, when WP already does that for you? https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Handling_Attributes

Comment: @Wiktor: wow... I'd have so many questions... this seems to work, thanks :)))

Comment: @CBroe: I've looked into that, but unless I have it completely wrong, that API doesn't actually retrieves the variables! "_In order to help set default values for missing attributes, and eliminate any attributes that are not recognized by your shortcode, the API provides a shortcode_atts() function_" This is to SET variables. Do you know a function which actually GETS all the shortcode attributes and serves them into an array?

Comment: @nico Wiktor's regex doesn't work if webm comes before mp4, check my answer and my working example.

Comment: The attributes _are_ in the `$atts` parameter passed to your shortcode function already.

Comment: @CBroe: don't wanna sound lazy, but could you walk me through how can I do that? should I do `$myarray = shortcode_atts($atts)`?

Comment: Just look at the examples on the documentation page, it’s all there already.

Comment: I looked at it. IT IS NOT CLEAR TO ME. Everywhere on that page I read about "setting default attributes". Seriously, if you know how to be helpful, be helpful.

Comment: I was away from the computer for an hour. If you want to get a helpful answer, please explain how you are using the regex. I suggest just parsing the shortcode with [`(?:\[video\s+|(?!^)\G)\s*(?<name>\w+)="(?<value>[^"]+)"`](https://regex101.com/r/kP7vE7/1) and then check if I have the value I need. Or with the [`(?:\[video\s+|(?!^)\G)\s*(?<name>[^=]+)="(?<value>[^"]+)"`](https://regex101.com/r/kP7vE7/2) regex.

Comment: @Wiktor: my comment above yours was addressed to CBroe. You were very helpful, thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
\[video(?:.*?(?:webm|mp4)="([^"]*)")?(?:.*?(?:webm|mp4)="([^"]*)")?.*\]\[\/video\]
```

working example: https://regex101.com/r/tC1aE3/5

Comment: I see what this would be better, but it fails for me in this kind of example, with the "poster" attribute: `[video width="720" height="1280" mp4="http://path-to-video/VID_20160118_134920.mp4" autoplay="true" poster="http://path-to-image/2016-01-23-16_23_45-Export-Settings-1.jpg"][/video]`